# How to replicate data from table of one database to table in another database atomically in SQLite in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios-sqlite

I have tried to prepare `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_step` the following two statements:

```
@"delete from students;

@"insert into students select * from buffer.students;"
```

with `'buffer'` being the database being attached as the source.

However, this does not guarantee both two statements were executed in bundle.